# What does &p, if p is an pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

I have a question about pointers and address, I have searched and can not find information.

```
int* p = new int;
*p = 5;
std::cout << p; // Output the address of p.
std::cout << *p; //Output the value pointed by p.
std::cout << &p; // Output a address, but what address is that?
```

What does exactly &p, if p is an pointer?

Sorry for the english.

Comment: The address of the pointer.

Comment: It is the address of `p`, just like with anything else.

Comment: Every object has an address, and pointers are objects too.  By the way, your comment on the third line `"// Output the address of p."`, is wrong. That line outputs the *value* of `p`, which is the address of the thing `p` points to.

Comment: The output of `std::cout << p;` is *not* the address of `p`. It's the *value* of `p`. That value happens to be a pointer value (or, equivalently, an address).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Pointer lvalues, yes.  Pointer-typed rvalues can't have their address taken, because they aren't objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&p` gives the address of the pointer `p`.